# ChartJS dynamically adding values with jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to populate a piechart in ChartJS dynamically using data from a jQuery/AJAX query.

The only thing I am struggling with is creating the data in a format that chartJS understands. This is the required format:

```
var dynamicData = [
    { label: "One", value: 23 },
    { label: "Two", value: 33 },
    { label: "Three", value: 43 },
    { label: "Four", value: 53 },
]
```

When I try to create it, I get double quotes `""` around each set of data. I know it is a simple mistake but I can't figure it out. This is how I am creating the data (partial jQuery code):

```
.success(function(response) {
    if(!response.errors && response.result) {
        var doughnutData = [];
        $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
            doughnutData.push('{ label: "'+value[0]+'", value: '+value[2]+',color:"#F7464A" }');
       });

        console.log(doughnutData);

var doughnutOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke : true,
    segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",
    segmentStrokeWidth : 2,
    percentageInnerCutout : 50,
    animation : true,
    animationSteps : 100,
    animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",
    animateRotate : true,
    animateScale : true,
    onAnimationComplete : null
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart3").getContext("2d");
var mydoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(dynamicData, doughnutOptions);
    } else {
    alert("error");
    }
```

The console shows:

```
["{ label: "17x1p14e6662", value: 16,color:"#F7464A" }", "{ label: "8734hjgfd784ew", value: 8,color:"#F7464A" }"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is outputting the object as a string because you are pushing a string to the **var doughnutData**, you are doing this wrapping the object in quotes and concatenating the values to the string therefor treating the argument passed to the push method as a string type.

The proper way to use the push method to add an object to an array would be like this.

```
array.push({property:'string', property:2})
```

Meaning your code should look like this.

```
doughnutData.push({ label:value[0], value:value[2],color:"#F7464A" });
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a link on how the push method works on an array and [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects) is another link to javascript objects

Another thing is when you are creating the chart your are passing the **var dynamicData** instead of your **var doughnutData**.

Comment: Awesome! I understand the issue now. Thanks for taking the time to answer :)